# Magento 2 - XAMPP vs remote server. Which is best for development envirnoment?

Tags: magento2

We are a team of three developers and we want to develop a website on magento 2.
We have fresh installation of magento on a remote server. Is better to develop directly on a remote server or using XAMPP on windows locally?
if neither the two, do you recommend another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Make it on local server because our machine have mode ram and processing power then server.
and if it works on local machine just upload your modules on Server via some FTP client.
Hope it will Help.
if you feel localhost is slow consider following.

```
   1 php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
   2 php bin/magento c:enable
   3 `Use minifyed CSS and JS`
```

If any Question feel free to comment

Comment: I installed it locally on XAMPP but it is slow

Comment: please  disable chache i and adding commands in edited post

Comment: Much faster on a remote server if it has some decent processing power and RAM.  The time is taken in the processor processing, not transferring the data over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 is extremely slow on Windows machine. If you want to develop your website locally, I would recommend using Virtual environment like [Bitnami Lamp VM](https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp/virtual-machine).

You can check https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/infrastructure/lamp/ for more information.

Otherwise, if you are a bit familiar with Linux but don't want to install it completely, you can try out https://medium.com/@ssharizal/how-to-install-lamp-stack-server-on-windows-subsystem-linux-wsl-windows-10-133419c22473